# Submit dojo editor contents with form submission

Tags: dojo, rich-text-editor

Presently because of  "onchange" the editor contents are submitted only if the contents of editor change. How do I make sure that the dojo editor contents are submitted everytime a form a submitted irrespective of whether a change has occurred or not?

Code snippet:

```
<td>         
  <input type="hidden" name="editorContent" id='editorContent' value="replaced by dijit.Editor content onsubmit" /> 
  <div dojoType="dijit.Editor" id="content" onChange="dojo.byId('editorContent').value = this.getValue();"     plugins="['foreColor','|','bold','italic','underline','|','createLink', 'unlink']"                 extraPlugins="['dijit._editor.plugins.AlwaysShowToolbar']">                     
</div>             
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a simple onSubmit handler to do this, though the way you have the code structured, initializing the hidden field to the loaded value should accomplish the same thing.